# Connecting Rundeck with MySql Database

Tags: mysql, rundeck

I am trying to connect RunDeck with MySQL server but seeing below errors:-

```
org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: Error executing DDL via JDBC Statement
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:67)
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.applySqlString(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:524)
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.applySqlStrings(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:470)
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.applyIndexes(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:327)
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.GroupedSchemaMigratorImpl.performTablesMigration(GroupedSchemaMigratorImpl.java:84)
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.performMigration(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:203)
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.doMigration(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:110)
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.performDatabaseAction(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:176)
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.process(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:65)
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:478)
        at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:422)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:711)
        at org.grails.orm.hibernate.cfg.HibernateMappingContextConfiguration.buildSessionFactory(HibernateMappingContextConfiguration.java:276)
        at org.grails.orm.hibernate.connections.HibernateConnectionSourceFactory.create(HibernateConnectionSourceFactory.java:86)
        at org.grails.orm.hibernate.connections.AbstractHibernateConnectionSourceFactory.create(AbstractHibernateConnectionSourceFactory.java:39)
        at org.grails.orm.hibernate.connections.AbstractHibernateConnectionSourceFactory.create(AbstractHibernateConnectionSourceFactory.java:23)
        at org.grails.datastore.mapping.core.connections.AbstractConnectionSourceFactory.create(AbstractConnectionSourceFactory.java:64)
        at org.grails.datastore.mapping.core.connections.AbstractConnectionSourceFactory.create(AbstractConnectionSourceFactory.java:52)
        at org.grails.datastore.mapping.core.connections.ConnectionSourcesInitializer.create(ConnectionSourcesInitializer.groovy:24)
        at org.grails.orm.hibernate.HibernateDatastore.<init>(HibernateDatastore.java:201)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:142)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:122)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:271)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1201)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1103)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:513)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:312)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:308)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:351)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:108)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveConstructorArguments(ConstructorResolver.java:648)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:145)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1201)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1103)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.getSingletonFactoryBeanForTypeCheck(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:931)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.getTypeForFactoryBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:808)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isTypeMatch(AbstractBeanFactory.java:564)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doGetBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:432)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:395)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanFactoryUtils.beanNamesForTypeIncludingAncestors(BeanFactoryUtils.java:206)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1267)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1101)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1066)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:835)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:741)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:467)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1181)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1075)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:513)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:312)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:308)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
        at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.registerBeanPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:225)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.registerBeanPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:703)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:528)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303)
        at grails.boot.GrailsApp.run(GrailsApp.groovy:84)
        at grails.boot.GrailsApp.run(GrailsApp.groovy:393)
        at grails.boot.GrailsApp.run(GrailsApp.groovy:380)
        at grails.boot.GrailsApp$run.call(Unknown Source)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:47)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:116)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:136)
        at rundeckapp.Application.main(Application.groovy:27)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:50)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.WarLauncher.main(WarLauncher.java:59)
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: INDEX command denied to user 'rundeck'@'10.0.0.8' for table 'base_report'
```

Here is my rundeck-config.properties file

```
#loglevel.default is the default log level for jobs: ERROR,WARN,INFO,VERBOSE,DEBUG
loglevel.default=INFO
rdeck.base=/var/lib/rundeck
#rss.enabled if set to true enables RSS feeds that are public (non-authenticated)
rss.enabled=false
# change hostname here
grails.serverURL=http://10.0.0.8:4440
dataSource.dbCreate = update
dataSource.url = jdbc:mysql://my-dev.************.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com:3306/rundeck?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false
dataSource.username = rundeck
dataSource.password = ***************
dataSource.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
rundeck.log4j.config.file = /etc/rundeck/log4j.properties
```

I have copied JDBC driver as well to /var/lib/rundeck/libext

```
[rundeck@mysever]$ pwd && ls -ld mysql-connector-java-5.1.46
/var/lib/rundeck/libext
drwxr-xr-x 3 rundeck rundeck 4096 Feb 26 13:28 mysql-connector-java-5.1.46
```

I have followed instructions here:
http://rundeck.org/2.10.6/administration/setting-up-an-rdb-datasource.html#setup-mysql

Even though I can see table structure in my RDS but there is no entry in any of the table

```
mysql> show tables;
+----------------------------+
| Tables_in_rundeck          |
+----------------------------+
| auth_token                 |
| base_report                |
| execution                  |
| job_file_record            |
| log_file_storage_request   |
| node_filter                |
| notification               |
| orchestrator               |
| plugin_meta                |
| project                    |
| rdoption                   |
| rdoption_values            |
| rduser                     |
| referenced_execution       |
| report_filter              |
| scheduled_execution        |
| scheduled_execution_filter |
| storage                    |
| workflow                   |
| workflow_step              |
| workflow_workflow_step     |
+----------------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

```
INDEX command denied to user 'rundeck'@'10.0.0.8' for table 'base_report'
```

You have a permissions issue that is causing the Schema Migration to fail.  You should have run:

`GRANT ALL ON rundeck.* to rundeck;`

You can check the current permissions with:

`SHOW GRANTS FOR rundeck;`